# Difference between an FLTK Double Window and a FLTK Single Window

Tags: fltk

I'm confused about the difference between and [FLTK Single Window](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/classFl__Single__Window.html) and and [FLTK Double Window](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/classFl__Double__Window.html). In the FLTK 1.4.0 documentation for a double window, we get this description:

> The Fl_Double_Window provides a double-buffered window.
> If possible this will use the X double buffering extension (Xdbe). If not, it will draw the window data into an off-screen pixmap, and then copy it to the on-screen window.
> It is highly recommended that you put the following code before the first show() of any window in your program:
> Fl::visual(FL_DOUBLE|FL_INDEX)
> This makes sure you can use Xdbe on servers where double buffering does not exist for every visual.

What is a double-buffered window? What is an off-screen pixmap? In what kinds of cases would you want to use a Double Window vs a Single Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle of double buffering is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Software_double_buffering
Basically data is written to a buffer until it is time to draw.  Then the whole buffer is copied to video ram (bitblt in windows terminology).

Advantages: performance is smooth - there is no flickering.
Disadvantage: what you see on the screen is nanoseconds behind the data that is being written to the buffer.  Unless your eyes can work that quick, you will not notice the difference.

An off-screen pixmap just a pixmap.  The pixmap is the buffer that the code writes to.

You'd use single window for forms which don't change a lot like messageboxes or data entry forms.  If you are playing with graphics or displaying data that changes very quickly like countdown timers, sliders, meters etc then definitely use a double window.

FLTK is built on top of native graphics routines.  On Linux, that is X-Windows.  On MS-Windows, that is the windows SDK.  Calling certain routines can magically speed up the graphics on different platforms.

**Edit**

It is smooth because it writes to the hardware (paints) when the hardware is ready.  It is not writing more or less often but at the right time.

All sorts of strange effects can happen if the hardware is written to when it is not ready: flashing, rippling, blocking etc.

It does use more memory - about as much as the pixmap.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "performance"? Is it "smooth" becuase their is less time in between each "paint" of the gui? Also, does this mean a Double Window would use more RAM?